# Proper way to find the critical points of a 2 variable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I want to find the critical points of $g(x,y) = x^3 +y^3+3xy$

Do I need to find the points in which $\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta x} = 0 $ **AND**   $\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta y} = 0$ or do I need to find the points in which $\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta x} = 0$ **OR** $\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta 0} = 0$

In the first case I find that the critical points of g are (0,0); (1,1); (-1, 1); (1,-1) and in the case I find that the critical points of g are (0, 0); (1,1)

Comment: You need all partial derivatives 0.

Comment: Check your work. Most of the points you list aren’t critical points of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

A critical point for the function $g$ is indeed defined by $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 0 $ **AND** $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0 $.